# setValue() method in Firebase Database not working. Value is not getting added to the database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on a social media app. I don't know what exactly caused this but all of a sudden my like button has stopped functioning as the value is not getting added to my database.

Also, I'd like to add that when I use the same like code inside a PostDetailActivity which displays a single post, the like button works just fine. But when I use it in one fragment from MainActivity, that is where the problem is encountered.

**Here's my code for adding the like:**

The code is from my PostAdapter

```
databaseReferenceLikes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid());

        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {

                    databaseReferenceLikes.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
                            mutableData.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, @Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (b)
                                addNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());

                            if (databaseError != null)
                                databaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

                } else {

                    databaseReferenceLikes.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
                            mutableData.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(null);
                            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, @Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (b)
                                removeNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());

                            if (databaseError != null)
                                databaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
```

Except for the last post on the feed which works fine, every other post cannot be liked. I've tried removing the mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd() method and found that now the first post's like button functions and the rest don't. Since the likes are getting added for the first or last post inside the fragment, and inside PostDetailActivity, it is clear that the doTransaction method is getting executed but the setValue method doesn't add the value to database.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Can anybody explain what's causing this?

Comment: The solution is in your problem statement. The problem lies within your adapter, and most probably in the part "holder.like.getTag().equals("like")". Since you are using recyclerview, ensure that you are setting / resetting these tags properly. And btw, if you are handling the like button, what's the use of the "if" check at all?

Comment: The tag "like" is set when the post isn't liked yet. A post which is already liked has the tag "liked". That is how I'm differentiating between the liked and not liked post for that user and removing the like or adding the like respectively.

Comment: Where are you setting the tag after like?

Comment: possible to share your adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a reference variable `databaseReferenceLikes`, I used the train wreck code for that reference and it worked for me.

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
                        mutableData.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, @Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot != null) // No error has occurred
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(firebaseUser.getUid())) // Data is present at the location databaseReferenceLikes
                                if (b) { // Transaction was successfully completed
                                    addNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());
                                }

                        if (databaseError != null)
                            databaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
                        mutableData.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(null);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, @Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot != null) // No error has occurred
                            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(firebaseUser.getUid())) // Confirm that data is removed from location databaseReferenceLikes
                                if (b) // Transaction was successfully completed
                                    removeNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());

                        if (databaseError != null)
                            databaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The problem was that the data wasn't getting registered to the database. Well, now it does. Problem solved.